# How to get the latest file with multiple filters C#

Tags: c#, getfiles

I have this simple code which I need to update a little bit.

I need to update the list(this.FoundReports) with only the very latest file if multiple instances of the same file type are located in directories. .i.e _InputCounts or_OutputCounts.

How to do it with the existing code or maybe there is a better way?

Thanks

Comment: http://pastebin.com/XL37Cqks

Answer (score 0):

Here what you can do:

You can create a string[] array to store all the files information in that specific directory and them compare the dates of each file:

Try something like this:

```
path = locations of file
findname = file name you are looking for    

string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(path, findName);

            foreach (string dir in dirs)
            {
                DateTime lastupdatedate = File.GetLastWriteTime(dir);

                //here you compare last updated date and find your record. 
                if (lastupdatedate > previousLastupdated)
                {

                }

             }
```

Comment: thanks but i think this will require multiple runs to cover different findName. I could easily do http://pastebin.com/ZJDc8L2P to get result. I'm looking for a way without multiple loops through the file lists if that makes sense

Comment: Make senses. Thanks.